# Android getting storage location and saving downloaded file

Tags: android, path, storage, sd-card, fileoutputstream

In my Asynctask class doInBackground(String... aurl) , I use the following code to save the downloaded file. The file is saved in the same name as it is in the web server. But I heard that it is better to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(). Is it necessary? How do I use it in my code? Can someone show me? Thanks in advance

```
String fname;
 fname = data.proj.substring( data.proj.lastIndexOf('/')+1, data.proj.length() );

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+fname);
```

The code is working perfectly now, but I doubt it may cause problem sometimes in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of putting /sdcard/ you can put the following code:

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                .toString() + File.separator
```

and use path instead of /sdcard/